# Column Renaming in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have column names with special characters. I renamed the column and trying to save and it gives the save failed saying the columns have special characters. I ran the print schema on the dataframe and i am seeing the column names with out any special characters. Here is the code i tried.

```
for c in df_source.columns:
    df_source = df_source.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace( "(" , ""))
    df_source = df_source.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace( ")" , ""))
    df_source = df_source.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace( "." , ""))

df_source.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").option("header","true").save(stg_location)
```

and i get the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Number_of_data_samples_(input)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.
```

Also one more thing i noticed was when i do a df_source.show() or display(df_source), both shows the same error and printschema shows that there are not special characters.

Can someone help me in finding a solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using it as below -

**Input_df**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [("xyz", 1)]

schema = StructType([StructField("Number_of_data_samples_(input)", StringType(), True), StructField("id", IntegerType())])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

df.show()

+------------------------------+---+
|Number_of_data_samples_(input)| id|
+------------------------------+---+
|                           xyz|  1|
+------------------------------+---+
```

**Method 1**
`Using regular expressions` to replace the special characters and then use toDF()

```
import re

cols=[re.sub("\.|\)|\(","",i) for i in df.columns]
df.toDF(*cols).show()

+----------------------------+---+
|Number_of_data_samples_input| id|
+----------------------------+---+
|                         xyz|  1|
+----------------------------+---+
```

**Method 2**
`Using .withColumnRenamed()`

```
for i,j in zip(df.columns,cols):
    df=df.withColumnRenamed(i,j)

df.show()

+----------------------------+---+
|Number_of_data_samples_input| id|
+----------------------------+---+
|                         xyz|  1|
+----------------------------+---+
```

**Method 3**
`Using .withColumn` to create a new column and drop the existing column

```
df = df.withColumn("Number_of_data_samples_input", lit(col("Number_of_data_samples_(input)"))).drop(col("Number_of_data_samples_(input)"))

df.show()

+---+----------------------------+
| id|Number_of_data_samples_input|
+---+----------------------------+
|  1|                         xyz|
+---+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Method 3, helped a bit. I have to do bit of customization to the Method 3.